Attribute values in variable products on shop/categories WooCommerce pages
In an online store on WooCommerce, I use code that displays certain product attributes on archive/category pages.
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item_title', 'new_template_loop_product_meta', 20 );
function new_template_loop_product_meta() {
    global $product;

    $attrs_by_cats = [
        20 => [ 'pa_size' ],
    ];

    $attr_list = [
        'Size' => 'pa_size',
    ];

    if ( ! is_object( $product ) ) {
        $product = wc_get_product( get_the_id() );
    }

    $cats = $product->get_category_ids();

    if ( ! is_array( $cats ) ) {
        return;
    }

    $attrs = [];

    foreach ( $cats as $cat ) {
        if ( isset( $attrs_by_cats[ $cat ] ) ) {
            $attrs[] = $attrs_by_cats[ $cat ];
        }
    }

    $allowed_attrs = array_unique( array_merge( [], ...$attrs ) );

    echo '<div class="custom-attributes">';

    foreach ( $attr_list as $attr_title => $attr_name ) {
        if ( in_array( $attr_name, $allowed_attrs, true ) ) {
            show_attribute( $product, $attr_title, $attr_name );
        }
    }

    echo '</div>';
}
/* Show attr */
function show_attribute( $product, $attr_title, $attr_name ) {
if ( 'sku' === $attr_name ) {
    $attr = (string) esc_html( $product->get_sku() );
} else {
    $attr = $product->get_attribute( $attr_name );

    if ( ! $attr ) {
        return;
    }
    $attr = explode( ', ', $attr ); // convert the coma separated string to an array

    $attr_arr = []; // Initialize

    // Loop through the term names
    foreach ( $attr as $term_name ) {
        // Embed each term in a span tag
        $attr_arr[] = sprintf('<span class="attr-term">%s</span>', $term_name);
    }
    // Convert back the array of formatted html term names to a string
    $attr = implode(' ', $attr_arr);
}

if ( '' === $attr ) {
    return;
}

printf( '<div class="custom-attributes-text">%s: %s</div>', $attr_title, $attr);
}

With simple products this code works without problems. The problem is only with the attribute in variable products.
When creating a product I added sizes S, M, L and automatically created variations. Then for each size S, M and L I manually set the stock availability to 30.
Then, the size L is all sold out and I have 0 in stock. Except that on the product list page all sizes are shown, while S and M should be shown.
How can I fix this code so that it works with variable products?
Thanks in advance for your help!

In show_attribute() function you have to check if it is a simple or variable product and if its a variable product you need to grab variations $product->get_available_variations() then loop variations and check if the variation has this attribute and is it in stock

Conditions that check the stock status in your show_attribute function were missing, you can add them by following below code, replace your show_attribute function with this.
function show_attribute( $product, $attr_title, $attr_name ) {
    if ( 'sku' === $attr_name ) {
        $attr = (string) esc_html( $product->get_sku() );
    } else {
        // ===============>
        $stock_status = $product->get_stock_status();
        if ( $stock_status === 'outofstock' ) {
            return; // do not show size attributes if simple product is out of stock
        }
        // <===============

        $attr = $product->get_attribute( $attr_name );

        if ( ! $attr ) {
            return;
        }
        $attr = explode( ', ', $attr ); // convert the coma separated string to an array

        // ===============>
        $in_stock_attr = $attr;
        if ( $product->is_type( 'variable' ) ) {
            $product = new WC_Product_Variable( $product );
            $variations = $product->get_available_variations();
            $variations_ids = wp_list_pluck( $variations, 'variation_id' );
            if ( is_array( $variations_ids ) && ! empty( $variations_ids ) ) {
                foreach ( $variations_ids as $variation_id ) {
                    $variation = new WC_Product_Variation( $variation_id );
                    $stock_status = $variation->get_stock_status();
                    if ( $stock_status === 'outofstock' ) {
                        $variation_attr = $variation->get_attribute( $attr_name );
                        if ( ( $key = array_search( $variation_attr, $in_stock_attr ) ) !== false ) {
                            unset( $in_stock_attr[ $key ] ); // Do not pick out of stock attribute for display
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        $attr = $in_stock_attr;
        // <===============

        $attr_arr = []; // Initialize

        // Loop through the term names
        foreach ( $attr as $term_name ) {
            // Embed each term in a span tag
            $attr_arr[] = sprintf( '<span class="attr-term">%s</span>', $term_name );
        }
        // Convert back the array of formatted html term names to a string
        $attr = implode( ' ', $attr_arr );
    }

    if ( '' === $attr ) {
        return;
    }

    printf( '<div class="custom-attributes-text">%s: %s</div>', $attr_title, $attr );
}


Images to show how it works on my side:

How it looks on the shop page : img1
Simple product is in stock : img2
Variable product that has in stock and out-of-stock variations : img3


Read this first. Your $product has an is_type method and you can use it to check whether it's variable. If so, you can get_available_variations, loop the result and apply your logic accordingly.
if ( $product->is_type( 'variable' ) ) {
   $variations = $product->get_available_variations();
   foreach ( $variations as $variation ) {
       //Infer the size and the stock number from $variation and implement your logic
   }
}

You can also use get_children if that suits your needs better. So, you will need to revisit your show_attribute method, edit it, apply changes that reflect your logic regarding to product sizes and stock availability, using the resources described avoce.

Unfortunately, if I could do that, I wouldn't create a bounty. Can you help based on my code?

@Dmitry what's $attr containing after $attr = $product->get_attribute( $attr_name );?

Is it just the names of the pa_size attribute values there or did I misunderstand the question? LoicTheAztec helped with this code.

@Dmitry in order to help you with your code I would need to get information about how it is performing. I lack contextual information of your project, apart from the details you have given. So I would need to know the exact value of $attr after the operation. You likely want to condition $attr_arr[] = sprintf('<span class="attr-term">%s</span>', $term_name); for some of the variations, based on stock being 0. So I need to know how this array looks alike. I will likely have subsequent question(s) after you provide the exact value.
